# What does super.<method-name> do in ruby?

Tags: ruby, super

With the following code:

```
class ObjA
    def func
        puts "ObjA"
    end
end

module Mod
    def func
        puts "Mod"
    end
end

class ObjB < ObjA
    include Mod
    def func
        puts "super called"
        super
        puts "super.func called"
        super.func
    end
end
```

Running `ObjB.new.func` results in:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :002 > ObjB.new.func
super called
Mod
super.func called
Mod
NoMethodError: undefined method `func' for nil:NilClass
    from test.rb:19:in `func'
    from (irb):2
```

I understand what `super` does - it calls the current method on the superclass. `include Mod` makes Mod the next superclass so `Mod#func` is called.

However, what is `super.func` doing? I thought it would be equivalent to `super`, but while it does print out the same output, it also throws a `NoMethodError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `super.func` would do the same thing as any form of method chaining. It calls `super`, and then calls `func` on the result returned by `super`.

The `super` part would call `Mod#func`, which prints out "Mod", then calls `func` on the return value of `Mod#func`, ie nil (that's because `puts` returns nil). As nil doesn't have a `func` method, it says

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `func' for nil:NilClass
    from test.rb:19:in `func'
    from (irb):2
```

Comment: Thanks, that explains it (I tested by adding `ObjA.new` to the end of the `Mod#func` method - it results in no method error and prints out `ObjA`).